# Hetting error in react build with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, bundle

I am using react.js & web pack. when run the NPM  run build command get this error I am learning the how to make build with web pack so I try first time but getting this error. please help!

I write this code from some web pack  tutorial website.

```html
assets by status 1.05 KiB [cached] 2 assets
./src/index.js 796 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js 13:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const ProviderComponent = ()=>{
|   return (
>   <Provider store={store} >
|       <App/>
|     </Provider>

webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 1 error in 901 ms
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Web pack file

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    output :{
        path:path.join(__dirname,'/dist'),
        filename:'main.[fullhash].js'
    },
    module:{
        rules:[{
            test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude:/node_modules/,
        },
           {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                    { loader: 'less-loader' }
                ]
            },
        ]
        
    },
    resolve: 
    {
        mainFiles: ['index', 'Index'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx','.css'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        }
    }, 
    plugins:[
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template:'./public/index.html'
      })
    ],

    devServer:{
        host:'localhost',
        port:port,
        historyApiFallback:true,
        open:true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) in your `index.js` which is not standard javascript. Webpack by default can only transpile standard javascript, for transpiling JSX which is a react feature, you need to use something that can help webpack recognize the syntax of JSX, webpack calls this things [*loaders*](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/).

There are different loaders which you can use, here for example you should use [`babel-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader) to tell webpack how to understand JSX.

`babel-loader` internally uses [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) which is a library for transpiling non -standard javascript into standard javascript.

It's better to get familiar with Babel.js and then use it in webpack. But for now, what you need is this:

### Install babel (with `preset-react`) and `babel-loader`

```sh
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

### Add babel to your webpack `js|jsx` files rule

You can set babel options in the webpack config file like I'm doing here, or create a separate file for configuring babel itself. You can read more about it in [Babel.js docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage).

```js
...

module:{
        rules:[{
            test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude:/node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', "@babel/preset-react"]
                }
            }
        },

...
```

Comment: i already made babelrc file & this code is written {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
    ]
}  & i install this packages npm i --save-dev webpack webpack-dev-server webpack-cli
npm i --save-dev @babel/core babel-loader @babel/present-env @babel/presenr-react
npm install --save @babel/runtime
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime

Comment: @PuneetPhull ok then you need at least `use: 'babel-loader'` in your webpack config.

Comment: new error sir ERROR in ./src/index.js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.js)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError

(1:1) C:\Users\NK\Desktop\React project\flipkart\src\index.js Unknown word

> 1 | import React from 'react';
    | ^
  2 | import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3 | import './index.css';
 @ ./src/index.js 8:6-140 22:17-24 26:0-110 26:0-110 27:22-29 27:33-47 27:50-64

Comment: @PuneetPhull It's telling you have `CssSyntaxError`. Please read the error. Also, edit your comment and put the code and errors in backticks so it's readable.

Comment: `ERROR in ./src/index.js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.js)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
**CssSyntaxError**
(1:1) C:\Users\NK\Desktop\React project\flipkart\src\index.js Unknown word

> 1 | import React from 'react';
    | ^
  2 | import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3 | import './index.css';
 @ ./src/index.js 8:6-140 22:17-24 26:0-110 26:0-110 27:22-29 27:33-47 27:50-64`

Comment: I can't help you with some random error messages (although you have probably some CSS syntax errors). It's no longer related to the original post, try updating your question with more information or open a new question if you can't solve it yourself.

Comment: no problem sir thanks for your time i try some other code it generate the build but when i run it show manifest error in console then i undo the code